# Shell file parsing to automate youtube uploads

Tags: linux, shell, youtube

I was writing a small script to mass upload videos to youtube.. It looks like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
python --version
for file in ./*.mp4 ; do
        export title=$(basename "$file" ".mp4")
        echo $title "for" $file
        youtube-upload -m mail@mailer.com -p pass -c Category -t "$title" -d "description" "$file"
done
```

Where [youtube-upload](http://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload) is a cli based python uploader..

My question is as you can see i'm taking the title from the file name path, and the description is always the same :(. I want to write the description into a text or xml file parse it, and then upload with a proper description for each file..

How to do this using shell commands in this context?

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one file containing all of your filename->description mappings:

```
my file.mp4 this is a description
file2.mp4 this is another description
my last file.mp4 this is a description
ilied.mp4 description
```

And then just grab the line beginning with the filename and use the rest of the line:

```
#! /bin/sh
python --version
for file in ./*.mp4 ; do
        export title=$(basename "$file" ".mp4")
        echo $title "for" $file
        youtube-upload -m mail@mailer.com -p pass -c Category -t "$title" -d "$(grep "^$(basename "$file")" desc | sed 's/.*.mp4 //')" "$file"
done
```

Looking at what's in the `$(...)`:

```
grep "^$(basename "$file")" desc | sed 's/.*.mp4 //'
```

The `grep` finds the line that starts with the basename($file) in the "desc" file and then uses `sed` to get rid of the filename, leaving the rest of the line (which would be the description).

Note that this doesn't *need* to be a part of the `youtube-upload` comand line.  You can also toss it into a variable:

```
#! /bin/sh
python --version
for file in ./*.mp4 ; do
        export title=$(basename "$file" ".mp4")
        echo $title "for" $file
        description=$(grep "^$(basename "$file")" desc | sed 's/.*.mp4 //')
        youtube-upload -m mail@mailer.com -p pass -c Category -t "$title" -d "$description" "$file"
done
```